# Renaming column multiple ids in SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, alias

I have a table named users with a column id and another grade_id and a table nammed grades with an id and a name.

I want to SELECT all the users with their grades names so i did:

```
 SELECT * FROM users AS u, grades AS g WHERE g.id = u.grade_id
```

This return all the user with their grades name but it replace user.id by the grade id.

I'm new to sql and i don't know how to make it work, do you have an idea?

Comment: Since you are new to SQL, I would recommend to include just the data columns you need instead of using the `SELECT *` syntax... or at least be aware that `SELECT *` is a sloppy shortcut in many cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **ALIAS** name to column

Try this:

```
SELECT u.id AS userId, u.name AS userName, 
       g.id AS gradeId, g.name As grade
FROM users AS u
INNER JOIN grades AS g ON g.id = u.grade_id
```